# Finding the plane that contains both a given point and every point of a line.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to begin with this question as I've just started with linear algebra and its starting to become overwhelming.

Given this problem:

**Let L denote the line consisting of all points of the form (t, 0,2), where t can be any real number.**

**Let v denote the point (-1,2,2)**.

**Which of the following planes contain both v and every point of L?**

a) x=-1, y,z are any real numbers

b) z=2, x, y are any real numbers

c) y=2, x,z are any real numbers

The answer is apparently (b):  $z=2, x, y$ are any real numbers

What are the steps that I need to approach to get to this answer?

Comment: z is 2 and from here you see that a) or b) can not be a solution

Comment: @Moti b is a solution for that reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the answer choice planes contain $v$ so that isn't an issue.

For the line, we know that $c$ is not the correct option because it doesn't contain $y=0$.

We also know that $a$ is not the correct option because the line is parallel to the $x$ axis, and this plane only contains one $x$-value.

The correct answer is $b$ because $x$ and $y$ are allowed to vary, and then $z=2$ which agrees with the line.